RefSymbol of Pinia store
When I use Pinia in my Nuxt3 project:
const {isSomeFlag} = storeToRefs(someStore);

I see this type of isSomeFlag
isSomeFlag: Ref<{
    value: boolean
    [RefSymbol]: true
}>

instead
isSomeFlag: Ref<boolean>

Same problem is with arrays and objects and I have TS errors when I unref these Refs. But code is working correctly - only TS errors.
How to fix it?
"vue": "3.4.15",
"nuxt": "3.8.1",
"@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
"pinia": "^2.1.7",
I have tried to use properties of store directly
const isSomeFlag = someStore.isSomeFlag;

and it has type:
isSomeFlag: {
    value: boolean;
    [RefSymbol]: true;
}

But it is not reactive
I have tested storeToRefs on clear project (Vue3 + Pinia): it is correct Ref type


What is the error? If you see it in IDE only but the code works as intended, this should be considered IDE problem, unless proven otherwise.  someStore is not shown. The only possibility for "and it has type" would be that it's declared incorrectly

It seems OK here, T = Ref<string>

It was vue-demi package
I have removed this from tsconfig and incorrect types went away.
